# Worklight Javascript Adapter: Unable to retrieve array value passed as parameter to adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I pass a array to the Worklight adapter, and I am unable to retrieve the value in my array.

Inside my -impl.js file, i create a function like:

```
function getlist(list) {
   ...
}
```

list is an array. And in my adapter, I try to output the value.

```
WL.Logger.info(list);
WL.Logger.info(list.arr);
```

It output like:

```
[INFO    ] {
"arr": [
   {
     "a": "...",
     "b": "..."
   },
   {
     "a": "...",
    "b": "..."
  },
  {
    "a": "...",
    "b": "..."
  },

   ]
} [project test]
[INFO    ] undefined [project test]
```

I just do not get it. list is first output, which is fine. However, list.arr is the second one and it says undefined. Why list.arr is undefined?

No idea what is wrong.

WL verison: 6.0.0.20130614-0631

Comment: I might be misreading, but it appears to me that list is not an array, but an object. the curly braces {} designate an object whereas the square brackets [] designate an array. Can you confirm? EDIT: Oh nevermind, you were saying list as the parameter to the function. If you log list['arr'] does it work?

Comment: what is typeof list?  Is the array stringified?  What does JSON.parse(list) return?

Answer (score 1):

Your list argument IS an array. However the output of a WL.Logger.*() must always be an object (mandated by underlying JS engine). So your array is converted to object for logging purposes. E.g. if your list object is

[1,2,3]

the WL.Logger.debug(list) will be

{ arr: [1,2,3] }

The original object is not modified, it will remain an array. You can still get elements with list[0], list[1] etc.